# Question on informatica power center transformation task

Tags: sql, informatica

I have a source table containing first name and last name, but the cell next to first name is blank and cell prior to last name is blank. I want to place the last name right in front of first name

Source:

```
Firstname | lastname
ABC       | <blank>
<blank>   | DEF
GHI       |<blank>
<blank>   |JKL

Desired Output:
Firstname | lastname
ABC        | DEF
GHI        |JKL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregator with MAX() function.
Create an aggregator and define ports like this -

```
customer_id (set it as group by) - input+output port
in_Firstname = Firstname - input only port
in_lastname = lastname - input only port
out_Firstname = MAX(in_Firstname, NOT ISNULL(Firstname)) - output only port
out_lastname = MAX(in_lastname, NOT ISNULL(lastname)) - output only port
```

MAX along with NOT NULL function will eliminate all null data. Aggregator will produce only 1 row per customer. You can use sorter too to improve performance.

[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate more as this way is not working. I have tried this by using expression transformation and could change the first_name column as per target table, but unable to change last_name column as it is starting with (null). Please help

Comment: you need to use `aggregator` transformation and not expression transformation. I attached a screenshot of agg transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable to fill in the blank `Firstname`. Then eliminate rows without missing `lastname`.

Create the following ports:

```
[variable] v_prev_Firstname = IIF(ISNULL(Firstname), v_prev_Firstname, Firstname)
[output]   out_Firstname = IIF(ISNULL(Firstname), v_prev_Firstname, Firstname)
```

This should produce the following result:

```
Firstname | lastname
ABC       | <blank>
ABC       | DEF
GHI       | <blank>
GHI       | JKL
```

Now, use `Filter Tranformation` to remove the rows where `lastname` is `<blank>`.