# How to delete rows containing 'null' in informatica power center

Tags: sql, informatica

I have target table containing null values in specific column. I need to delete those rows from target table. Below is the scenario
target table:

```
firstname|lastname
null     |abc
def      |abc
null     |ghi
jkl      |ghi
```

I want to remove rows containing 'null'

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Solution given below is not efficient. Can you please give some example so i can help efficiently? I gave a solution of this issue in your question. You do not need to delete the data but you can use aggregator to exclude them from going into target.

Comment: Is this what you want  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202832/question-on-informatica-power-center-transformation-task?

Comment: Do you need to delete the EXISTING data in existing, target table? Or do you need to PREVENT such data from being stored in your target table?

Comment: yes, I want to delete entire record containing null

Answer (score 0):

You can replace to null values with an expression object in Informatica Mapping or you can use Informatica worklet and delete null values by T-SQL command within the worklet.